# Java - Parameter declaration

Tags: java, constructor

I'm studying this piece of code, it is a constructor with several parameters. The declaration of the last parameter with ... What does this mean?

```
    /**
 * Public constructor.
 * @param servicePort the service port
 * @param nodeAddresses the node addresses
 * @param sessionAware true if the server is aware of sessions, false otherwise
 * @throws NullPointerException if the given socket-addresses array is null
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the given service port is outside range [0, 0xFFFF],
 *    or the given socket-addresses array is empty
 * @throws IOException if the given port is already in use, or cannot be bound
 */
public TcpSwitch(final int servicePort, final boolean sessionAware, final InetSocketAddress... nodeAddresses) throws IOException {
    super();
    if (nodeAddresses.length == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    this.serviceSocket = new ServerSocket(servicePort);
    this.executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    this.nodeAddresses = nodeAddresses;
    this.sessionAware = sessionAware;

    // start acceptor thread
    final Thread thread = new Thread(this, "tcp-acceptor");
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: It's a [vararg parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is called varargs, look here for more http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

> The three periods after the final parameter's type indicate that the final argument may be passed as an array or as a sequence of arguments. Varargs can be used only in the final argument position.

As you can see in your code in this case it is an array.

Answer (score 3):

The parameter :

```
final InetSocketAddress... nodeAddresses
```

means a variable arguments. It can take 1 or more variable with the same data type as parameter to the function.

See : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html